# Triggering a Jenkins job from slave through Jenkins API request

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am designing a setup to run a python script on a windows machine remotely. I am planning to install python and Jenkins as a windows service on this machine (alternatively with docker). The intention is that multiple users will be able to send a request to a Jenkins API endpoint and this will trigger the same build that runs a shell command and run that python script. Master and node pcs are in a company network so security would not be an issue in the first place.

I would like to know the possibility of doing this as I planned and I appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. 
You can introduce with python api reference

https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful in some stage when I need to reach to jenkins host programmatically from client. My question is more about the archtitecture for remote accessing jenkins from public ip and triggering a job. More about Jenkins capabilities actually.